# Should I disable create-react-app serviceWorker in Electron app?

Tags: electron, create-react-app

I'm building a web application based on create-react-app, redux, react-router and electron. The app will run both as a web-app and as a electron-app. For the web-app I can totally see the point of having the serviceWorker from CRA - create-react-app, included to enable caching of resources.

But my gut feeling tells me that I should remove the call to registerServiceWorker(); in the electron-app? But I'm not sure.. Do I gain any advantages by keeping it there?